# How to make a popup with GET/POST request ASP NET CORE

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, get

I have a map, with `n` numbers of markers with a unique ID. When I click on them a custom popup for that marker appears (using JS and CSS). Every time I click on one of the markers, I want it to send a `POST` request that will change the URL from `~/reports/index` to `~report/index/custom_Id`. I need it to be with a custom id in the URL because I need to load some popups from another page using `GET` request.

## My code:

### Load map:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var layers = [new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM() })];

    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            zoom: 5,
            center: [166326, 5992663]
        }),
        interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({ altShiftDragRotate: false, pinchRotate: false }),
        layers: layers
    });

    const options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 5000,
        maximumAge: 0
    };

    function togglePopup(id) { //The function that revals the popup
        document.getElementById("overlay-container-" + id).classList.toggle("active");
    }

    // Vector Feature Popup logic
    map.on('click', function (e) { //The "sensor" that detects if a marker has been clicked.
        map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function (feature, layer) {
        
        togglePopup(feature.getId());
        resetCurrent();
        handleImages(feature.getId());
    })
})
```

### Add markers (this is inside a bigger for loop):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    markers = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector(),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
            anchor: [0.5, 1],
            src: 'https://ucarecdn.com/4b516de9-d43d-4b75-9f0f-ab0916bd85eb/marker.png' // => https://app.uploadcare.com/projects/c05bbeb5e1a61e862903/files/7110cd57-b0ee-4833-bcd1-ff0343dd01cc/?limit=100&ordering=-datetime_uploaded
            })
        })
    });

    map.addLayer(markers);

    var marker = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point([parseFloat(@_Data.coordLat), parseFloat(@_Data.coordLong)]));
    marker.setId(@_Data.Id);
    markers.getSource().addFeature(marker);
</script>
```

I know that if it was a `HTML` button for something like that I could have add `asp-route-id=@_Data.Id` or something but this is JS. How can I make it?

Comment: seems like a standard POST with a redirect (GET or a callback that sets window.location for a GET)  would do what you are asking.  (though I'm not real sure I'm understanding the question...)

Comment: I'll summarize the question here, I have a map with marketers, and whenever I click on one of those markers a popup appears (with CSS) with the information that it holds.  
I want to make that when I click on a marker it will change the URL to the same path with 'URL/the id of the marker. I want it to be like that because in the main screen I have four "links" that if I click on then I want then to redirect me to their marker's popup. I don't really know how to use POST/GET in JS so if you have an example close to what I am requesting please add it here. Thanks a lot. @pcalkins

Comment: Ajax: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp  Once you learn what it is you may want to use jQuery and use the .get() and/or .post() methods.  The basic idea is that JS makes the GET or POST and receives the data (in a callback you do what you want with that data)